# Design arrows in 3 axis with ARcore

Tags: android, arcore

I'm new in ARcore. We have a project in face recognition and we want to design a tool for users to help them to rotate their neck in the right direction to be frontal to the camera. We have values that show how much deviation we have in each axis. So, we just want to map these values to 3 arrows and, when a user is close to being frontal, the length of the arrows should decrease in each axis.

What I want to know is if it's possible to implement this with ARcore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewRenderable to add the values and make it a child of your arrow 3D object. Or you can try to make arrows yourself with ShapeFactory.
You might check out [this post](https://creativetech.blog/home/ui-elements-for-arcore-renderable) for more info